# How to set a value to a specific OID in SNMP Agent

Tags: erlang, snmp, erlang-otp

I am writing a SNMP Agent in erlang. I would like to set values to some OIDs and while I see functions like `snmpa:get/2` and `snmpa:get_next/2` I can not find any that would perform a set.
How do you set values in snmp agent in erlang?

Comment: The Erlang documentation provides an [Agent Implementation Example](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/snmp/snmp_impl_example_agent.html) that might help.

Comment: @SteveVinoski the only thing I could find there is: _This MIB is now loaded into the agent, and a manager can ask questions. As an example of this, we start another Erlang system and the simple Erlang manager in the toolkit._ That meqans I have to start a snmp manager, which I do not want to do (there is a lot of configuration). What I want to do is change a variable being the agent. Is that possible?

Comment: The snmpa module could have implemented a set/2 function but it hasn't.  This would be useful when using the default implementation.  Usually you will be implementing the instrumentation functions, and therefore the backing store, yourself.